# Is this Chinese Evergreen healthy? what should I do with the specifics?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, repotting

i got this Chinese Evergreen yesterday from a local nursery. I selected the best one from them(sadly they had only two small ones). Since it's better to buy small plants then big one, I chose this Evergreen. But I found some things that I am not quite sure what to do about.

What caused this:

[image]

What caused this tiny little hole?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The two white roots tell me the plant is quite healthy, right? But if it is healthy, what caused those two above mentioned problems? Should I re-pot it now? I got a small pot(bigger than its current pot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That holes in the leaf could be mechanical damage from being hit or it could be a virus/fungus/bacteria.  Given that the roots look healthy the plant should be able to outgrow either of these issues.

I would rake the soil to hinder the growth of the moss. Moss competes for moisture and nutrients. By next year you should be able to cut the new growth where it joins the large stem and propagate them in water.  Replant after they are rooted and you will have a plant with more stems.

Comment: That white spot is a hole. I can see through it. BTW, which one are you talking about? The first pic or the second one? Moss is bad for soil/plant?

Comment: @4-K amended answer